# Can I export blender facial motion capture

Tags: faces

I'm new to blender and have been following a tutorial on capturing face movement and transferring it to a model in blender. Is there a way to now export the data to the same model in a different program? That is, have all the facial animation data or transfer the model with the facial movements into another program preserving the data?